# Another chess problem

Tags: problems

The below puzzle **White to mate in two moves**. I tried all combinations. I can't figure it out how to solve this? I am starting to think this as a bug in my mobile application which is showing wrong information that it can be solved in just two moves.

```
[FEN "2K3Bn/B/3pp1N/1p1P3R/4k/R5q/N1P3Pp/7Q w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: There definitely is a checkmate in two moves, although it's not easy to find.

Comment: @chaosflaws if there is a way.. I will just froze here in shock. :)

Comment: This kind of question can be answered by using an online chessboard editor connected to an engine, for example a link like this (press FORCE COMPUTER TO MOVE) http://www.apronus.com/chess/playcomputer/?fen=02K3BnXB7X3pp1N1X1p1P3RX4k3XR5q1XN1P3PpX7Q_w_-_-_0_1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be fair, I tried solving this manually.

Qb1 works.

Basic idea - We see that the Black king cannot move. All that is needed is to give it a check. But where to give it a check from? The Black queen guards many key squares like h4, e3, c3, e1. Thus, White should try to find other squares. Qb1 threatens mate with Qb4+.

This is what I calculated -

```
1...exd5 2. Bxd5#
1...e5 2. Qb4#
1...b4 2. Qxb4#
1...h1=Q 2. Qb4#
1...Qxa3 2. c3!#
1...Qe1 2. Qxe1#
1...Qe3 2. Rxe3#
1...Qb3 2. cxb3#
1...Nxg6 2. Qb4#
```

I also confirmed with a computer that Qb1 is correct.

Comment: wow.. yeah.. any suggestions for me to become pro(_or atleast beginner_)? any book?

Comment: @Mr_Green, see my suggestions here - http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5208/where-i-can-start-to-learn/5213#5213

Comment: My first suggestion would be to stop looking at puzzles like this immediately. They are designed only for complexity/artistry/presentability. The chance of a position anything like this occurring in a real game is close to nonexistant, you're much better off looking at puzzles that present more likely/real situations.

Comment: @GrizzyRawrz I used to think the same way, but my mom once bought me a 200 chess problems book (all mates in 2 and complex positions which wouldn't occur in real life). I noticed that after attempting to solve them, my tactical ability was greatly sharpened, even for the "regular" puzzles.

Comment: You missed 2...Qc3 2. Nxc3#