# How to start learning chess?

Tags: learning, rules, beginner

I have always wanted to learn how to play chess, but I don't know how to start. I downloaded chess apps on my smartphone and PC but I didn't learn anything. I also contacted some local chess clubs to subscribe but they couldn't help me further.

My question is: What should I do to become a good chess player and learn the rules of the game very fast?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be migrated to Chess SE instead of meta ?

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen The guy has already some skills, I don't. The website of Andrew is really good for people with zero knowledge.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. You're asking two questions one of which is how to become a good chess player which is a duplicate of https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5208/where-can-i-start-to-learn and the other of which is new asking how to learn the rules of chess. You actually asked how to quickly learn the rules. I think that normally, that would be a question without much effort to figure out what you really want and explain it clearly, because it gives no backup plan for what you want if that can't be done. However, I believe I have an answer that clearly explains all the

Comment: rules of chess in a nutshell. Maybe if you ask another question to not invalidate any answers to this question just about how to learn the rules of chess, I will be able to answer it. However if it's not that good and it doesn't already have an answer, I guess I'll do you a favour by not writing an answer so that you will feel free to edit it and vote to close it but not to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a subjective answer (and a self-plug), but I believe that you'll find my website [Chesscademy](http://www.chesscademy.com) very helpful in learning the ropes. You can watch videos, tackle exercises, and complete quizzes. The educational material is structured such that even someone who has never even heard of chess before can easily get started.

Comment: Does it have responsive behaviour?

Comment: Not as much as I'd like, but we're currently redesigning the site's architecture to make it completely responsive. We'll push it out sometime tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The step from learning the rules to becoming a good player is pretty huge. Try taking one step at the time and feel your way forward. Chess is an amazing world filled with beauty and pain. If a passion awakens within you, then you will be hungry for more and there are tons of resources available both online and offline to guide your way to improved skills. Get a decent beginner's book, that is one possible starting point. Visit the local library and play over the board with people, or just watch for starters.

Chess is more than winning and losing. It is about human interaction, building new bonds, finding something in common. Chess really connects people. I guess what I am trying to say is that the over the board experience, meeting friends and sharing the passion for chess is a huge part of it. Don't just be at the computer and don't restrict yourself to online chess. I think that online chess is just an unfortunate trade-off that has to be done in order to save time in our everyday busy life. At least in the beginning, chess can and should be an over the board experience. With a real chess board in front of you and a nice book in hand.