# Which chess courses should I start with?

Tags: beginner

I know the rules and played with my friends but without any knowledge of opening tactics etc. And all material I could find online was not in an ordered manner . So can you suggest some courses I can enroll myself online which cover the basics going all the way to the advanced level ?( I am an absolute beginner)

P.S.: Free resources would be more appreciable because I am just a student . Thanks

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5208/where-can-i-start-to-learn ?

Comment: I am actually looking for some proper courses online (free or paid ) not all sorts of resources.

Answer (score 1):

The Elo rating system is quite simple in an essence, and functions as such:
By beating a higher rated player, you accumulate more Elo rating points than if you were to beat a lower rated player. (Elo rating points basically measure your chess aptitude).

As for the other aspects that you have mentioned, I would recommend that you visit chess.com and lichess.com.

Comment: How'd you add an answer to a question marked as "on hold"?

Comment: @ D M  I simply finished writing up my answer prior to the moment it was marked "on hold." That is not to say, for all those that may be mistaken, I wrote this 34 mins ago. In fact, I wrote it yesterday, but posted it today.

Comment: Indeed that is the logical explanation as to why I was able to answer a question marked as "on hold."